# Java's CompletableFuture and Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I want to launch threads with `CompletableFuture` Java 8-9, using Asynchronous mode, these are my classes and my threads:

I have 3 threads. My classes contain a single method `myMethod()`

```
Class_1 class_1 = new Class_1();

Class_2 class_2 = new Class_2(); 

Class_3 class_3 = new Class_3();
```

Setting up my `Runnable`s as below :

```
Runnable runnableClass_1 = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        class_1.myMethod();
        try { Thread.sleep(0); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
};

Runnable runnableClass_2 = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        class_2.myMethod();
        try { Thread.sleep(0); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
};

Runnable runnableClass_3 = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        class_3.myMethod();
        try { Thread.sleep(0); } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
};
```

Creating Threads :

```
Thread t_1 = new Thread( runnableClass_1 );

Thread t_2 = new Thread( runnableClass_2 );

Thread t_3 = new Thread( runnableClass_3 );
```

Finally, my question is how do I launch these three Threads using `CompletableFuture` Asynchronous mode.

Comment: If you don't need to control the thread handling yourself, you can simply use [`CompletableFuture.runAsync()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-). If you need more control, use the version with the `Executor` parameter and customize your `Executor`. Lastly, if you _really_ need to use those specific 3 threads, you have to manage the `CompletableFuture`s yourself inside the `Runnable`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can implement the same:

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

        CompletableFuture<Void> run1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                pauseSeconds(2);
                results.add("first task");
            }, service);

        CompletableFuture<Void> run2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                pauseSeconds(3);
                results.add("second task");
            }, service);

        CompletableFuture<Void> finisher = run1.runAfterBothAsync(run2,
                                            () -> results.add(results.get(0)+ "&"+results.get(1)),service);
         pauseSeconds(4);
         System.out.println("finisher.isDone() = "+finisher.isDone());
         System.out.println("results.get(2) = "+results.get(2));
//       assert(finisher.isDone(), is(true));
//       assertThat(results.get(2),is("first task&second task"));
        }

public static void pauseSeconds(int num){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(num);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How you setup (and possibly combine) your futures depends on your usecase: Do those futures depend on each other? Do you need to execute them sequentially or can you run them in parallel? Do you care about all three results or do you just need whichever future completes first?

Depending on your answer you can use the `flatMap/bind` combinators (they have different names for `CompletableFuture` but you can work that out) to chain your futures sequentially or you can spawn all of your futures from your current thread (letting them run in parallel) and then wait for all of them to have completed. You may also specify a specific thread pool to `CompletableFuture` factory methods of just use the default (ForkJoinPool).

All of this can be done quite succinctly with a monadic version of `Future` as provided by [vavr](http://vavr.io). But you could also come up with a solution using `CompletableFuture` if you take a look at its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

**Update/requested Example**:

The following example is basically taken from the [Java 8 in Action github repository](https://github.com/java8/Java8InAction/blob/master/src/main/java/lambdasinaction/chap11/Util.java), where the provided futures are run in parallel and the result of all of them is accumulated into a collection. What you do is, you transform a `List<Future<T>>` into a `Future<List<T>>`.

```
    final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    final CompletableFuture<String> foo = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        final long timeout = 500;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("foo on %s sleeping for %s", Thread.currentThread(), timeout));
        return "foo";
    });
    final CompletableFuture<String> bar = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        final long timeout = 100;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("bar on %s sleeping for %s", Thread.currentThread(), timeout));
        return "bar";
    });
    final CompletableFuture<String> baz = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        final long timeout = 1000;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("baz on %s sleeping for %s", Thread.currentThread(), timeout));
        return "baz";
    });

    CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> Stream.of(foo, bar, baz).map(future -> future.join()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .thenAccept(done -> System.out.println(String.format("Done with all futures %s", done)))
            .thenRun(() -> System.out.println(String.format("Running all futures in parallel took %s millis", System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)));
```

The output should be something like this:

```
bar on Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2,5,main] sleeping for 100
foo on Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9,5,main] sleeping for 500
baz on Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-11,5,main] sleeping for 1000
Done with all futures [foo, bar, baz]
Running all futures in parallel took 1007 millis
```

Comment: i'm interested by saving time max possible, before i used `CompletableFuture`, i had a very limited memory so i used `sequential` mode, now i augumented my memo then the processor, i'm interesed by using `CompletebleFuture` in `parallel`, can you give an example please.

Comment: i accept your answer Rea, i have been apported some modification but the your main method is pefectly preserved, ;)

Comment: @YohanT Sry to have been confusing you. When I was talking about accepting my answer, I was referring to the feature here on StackOverflow of "accepting an answer". You can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/tour